# Why is -webkit-filter not working for nested elements?

Tags: css

There seems to be an issue with turning off `-webkit-filter` in chrome.

It also doesn't seem to work how I would expect in firefox 34.0.5, or firefox 35 for that matter, when using the non-browser-specific `filter` css property.

Apparently, the property *should* be available, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Given the following code snippet (or [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/alanhogan/pen/jOYJjvQ)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  <style>
    #outer {
      background: blue;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

    #outer #inner {
      background: green;
      -webkit-filter: none; 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    outer
    <div id="inner">inner</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bottom line, why isn't `div#inner` getting its filter turned off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how `filter` works: the filter isn't inherited like other CSS properties, it's just applied once to the div's rendered contents. So your inner div gets no filter applied, then your outer div, which contains your inner div, has the filter applied to it.

`filter` is a compositing operation: the content of the outer box is rendered, then the `filter` is applied. You can't "turn off" a filter on the inner box because it's not applied at that level.

Think of it like picture-in-picture: you have your outer image, you paste on your inner image, then you take the resulting image and apply a the grayscale effect. That's essentially what the browser is doing here.

Basically, it works like this:

[image: Visual diagram of compositing process for inner/outer]

If you want it to work, you could make your inner div be on a completely separate layer. That is, make your "outer" div into a lower layer div and make your "inner" div into a higher layer div drawn *above*/in front of the lower layer div, rather than being contained within it:

[image: Visual diagram of compositing process for higher/lower]

Comment: Oh interesting, that seems so weird and totally counter to how CSS should work :(

Comment: @zealoushacker Well, this is also how things like `alpha`, `transform`, `width`, `height` and so on work. Anyway, I added some diagrams and suggested a potential solution. :)

Comment: I hope that can help you.

Comment: So basically `position: absolute` + `zindex`, go. =)

Comment: @zealoushacker Yeah, exactly. :)